# C# 7.0 Feature or what - [ClassName] obj when obj.Type is SomeType some

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-7.0

I have been recently assigned to a project which is using C# 7.0. While I was debugging the code I came across some switch case statement and in that it was written something like below:

```
switch (message)
{
    case  MyClass obj when obj.Type is MyType type:
     // Dome Action
    break;
    case  MyClass1 obj when obj.Type is MyType1 type:
     // Some Action
    break;
}
```

I want to understand the purpose behind this magical statement.

Comment: Have you even tried to google it? Hint: "C# 7 new features" will give you thousands of links where that code is explained. The feature is called *pattern matching* by the way.

Comment: [What's new in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7)

Comment: I would [read the announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/). Answering this question effectively means rewriting the documentation there already is.

Comment: Well thanks for the information. I dint have word "Pattern Matching" in my mind :)

Comment: @user2988458 You didn't need to, as was mentioned, you only needed to search for the new feature list to see what the new features are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the code you have posted is valid. If so, then `MyClass` has a field or property of type `MyType` called `Type`. Likewise `MyClass1` has a field/property `Type` that is of type `MyType1`.

So what the code is doing can be expressed as follows using C# 6 syntax:

```
if (message is MyClass)
{
    MyClass obj = message as MyClass;
    MyType type = obj.Type;
    // Dome Action
}
else if (message is MyClass1)
{
    MyClass1 obj = message as MyClass1;
    MyType1 type = obj.Type;
    // Some Action
}
```

The `case  MyClass obj` part is equivalent to the `is` and `as` expressions: it tests that `message` is of that type and then introduces `obj` as a new variable of that type.

The `when obj.Type is MyType type` part is an always-true when guard that is using the `x is T y` pattern to read `obj.Type` and assign it to a newly introduced variable `type`.